# Linear recurrence relation implementation in Haskell too slow

Tags: haskell

I have implemented a code that generate the infinite sequence given the base case and the coefficients of a linear recurrence relation.

```
import Data.List
linearRecurrence coef base | n /= (length base) = []
                           | otherwise = base ++ map (sum . (zipWith (*) coef)) (map (take n) (tails a))
  where a     = linearRecurrence coef base
        n     = (length coef)
```

Here is a implementation of Fibonacci numbers.
    fibs = 0 : 1 : (zipWith (+) fibs (tail fibs))

It's easy to see that

```
linearRecurrence [1,1] [0,1] = fibs
```

However the time to calculate `fibs!!2000` is 0.001s, and around 1s for `(linearRecurrence [1,1] [0,1])!!2000`. Where does the huge difference in speed come from? I have made some of the functions strict. For example, `(sum . (zipWith (*) coef))` is replaced by `(id $! (sum . (zipWith (*) coef)))`, and it did not help.

Comment: Did you use criterion to measure this? If not, do it to verify that your measurements aren't just a bad coincidence.

Comment: I just ran this through criterion (with `-O2`) on my netbook, and I get roughly a 10x difference between the two, not anything near the 1000x you claim to be seeing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are computing `linearRecurrence coef base` repeatedly. Make use of sharing, as in:

```
linearRecurrence coef base | n /= (length base) = []
                           | otherwise = a
  where a = base ++ map (sum . (zipWith (*) coef)) (map (take n) (tails a))
        n = (length coef)
```

Note the sharing of `a`.

Now you get:

```
*Main> :set +s
*Main> fibs!!2000
422469...
(0.02 secs, 2203424 bytes)
*Main> (linearRecurrence [1,1] [0,1])!!2000
422469...
(0.02 secs, 5879684 bytes)
```